# Using Map to extract elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, homework

I am given this problem.

```
planets = 
  {{Beta Pictoris B, D, {7, 1.6}}, 
   {WASP52B, T, {0.453, 1.270}}, 
   {Kepler426b, T, {1.0, 1.090}}, 
   {CoRoT6b, T, {2.95, 1.166}}, 
   {Kepler34b, R, {0.220, 0.784}}, 
   {Kepler367b, R, {0.0037, 0.116}}, 
   {Kepler200c, R, {0.0119, 0.142}}};
```

> Q. Using the Mathematica function Map and a suitably chosen function, generate a new list containing only the names of the planets

I have done this using `Extract`, which works fine, but I'm not sure of how to do this with Map.

```
f = Table[Extract[planets, {i, 1}], {i, 1, 7}]
```

Comment: just use `planets[[All, 1]]` (see [`Part  [[..]]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) in the docs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *have to* use `Map`:

```
Map[First, planets]
```

> {B Beta Pictoris, WASP52B, Kepler426b, CoRoT6b, Kepler34b, Kepler367b, Kepler200c}

Otherwise, you can use [`Part [[..]]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

```
planets[[All, 1]]
```

> {B Beta Pictoris, WASP52B, Kepler426b, CoRoT6b, Kepler34b, Kepler367b, Kepler200c}

Answer (score 0):

A restatement of kglr's answer in mathematica shorthand:

```
#[[1]] & /@ planets
```

Comment: Or `# & @@@ planets` for shortshorthand...